# Get the dynamically created selected radio button value using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the selected radio button's value. These values are fetched from a MySQL database bound to the controls. When the program executes, it returns null when I check the selected radio buttons value.
Help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Snippets of my file are as follows:

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <h3><?php echo $_SESSION['Question'] ?></h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="<?php $_SESSION['Option1'] ?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['Option1'] ?><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="<?php $_SESSION['Option2'] ?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['Option2'] ?><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="<?php $_SESSION['Option3'] ?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['Option3'] ?><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="<?php $_SESSION['Option4'] ?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['Option4'] ?><br/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="button_start" value="Start"/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="button_Back" value="Back"/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="button_save" value="Save"/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="button_Next" value="Next"/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="button_Submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
function Save($question_id)
{
    if (isset($_POST['button_save'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['radio'])) {
            $selectedValue = $_POST['radio'];
            if (is_null($selectedValue) || $selectedValue == "") {
                echo "Please select an option";
            } else {
                $connectionString = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "knowellaptitudetest");
                if (!$connectionString) {
                    echo "Error unable to connect to MySQL" . PHP_EOL;
                    echo "Debugging error no." . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
                    echo "Debugging error" . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
                    exit;
                }
                if ($selectedValue == $_SESSION['Correct_Answer']) {
                    //save and update marks for correct ans
                    $marks = 1;
                    $query = "INSERT INTO section_marks VALUES('" . $question_id . "','" . $marks . "')";
                    $result = mysqli_query($connectionString, $query);
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                } else {
                    //save and update marks for wrong answer
                    $marks = -1;
                    $query = "INSERT INTO section_marks VALUES('" . $row['Question_ID'] . "','" . $marks . "')";
                    $result = mysqli_query($connectionString, $query);
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                }
                mysqli_close($connectionString);
            }
        }
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman Thanks. I am a beginner in PHP. I'll use the method that you have suggested for future references.

Comment: Good that you're learning, but it can be a bit of a minefield, especially on the public internet. [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) is a useful guide on how to survive your learning experience.

Comment: @tadman Noted and Bookmarked. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Also, you really should [indent your code](http://mrbool.com/importance-of-code-indentation/29079).

Comment: while coding i do. Here i didn't. Thanks for pointing out. @MatheusAzevedo

Comment: @AarthnaMaheshwari form action in your code  is empty.

Comment: @Ayush should I add the same page's address? as the code is in the same page.

Answer (score 1):

You have to echo the php variable in html.

```
 <input type="radio" name="radio" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Option1'] ?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['Option1'] ?><br/>
```

Comment: It's not getting the value!